# What type does the event passed to the listener for the IE 11 specific deactivate event have?

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer-11

This is a common event in my code. I know what type onChange events are called with.

```
private onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    ...
};
```

But what type does the event passed to this event listener have?

```
// Since blur is asynchronous in IE11 we can't guarantee that a change
// will be saved onBlur when changing component model. The IE exclusive
// `deactivate` event triggers before any other click handlers.

this.inputRef.current!.addEventListener('deactivate', this.onDeactivate);

private onDeactivate = (e: any) => {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In `this.inputRef.current!.addEventListener('deactivate', this.onDeactivate);` if `current` is of type `HTMLInputElement` then `e` is of type `Event`.

## How to figure it out

Add a local function and hover over the argument to see its inferred type.

[image]

Here is the type for react onChange (what you already know):

[image]